# How can i insert documents to a collection in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am currently going through a hell of a time searching ways to actually fix this!!!

I am trying to insert a single document to a collection called 'newMongoDB_01'
after successfully executing the below code, it is still not inserted. I tried few ways to 'await'  the 'mongoose.connect()' method but didn't succeed.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/newMongoDB_01", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Pname: String,
  Price: Number,
  Category: [String],
  onSale: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

const Product01 = new Product({
  Pname: "Pepsi",
  Price: "40",
  Category: ["Drinks"],
});

Product01.save().then(() => {
  console.log("Data inserted successfully");
});
```

I need to insert that document to that collection without fail.
Any help with this is highly appreciated and thanks in advance